# jquery html markup validator

Tags: jquery, html, markup, validation

I am trying to find a jquery plugin that can validate html markup (which checks whether the html markup is proper or not).

Here's how I intend to work.

I enter the html string in textarea and the jquery plugin must validate whether the tags are complete or not.

It must report if there is any closing tag missing etc etc

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing. Usually by time the DOM is ready the browser will have "completed" the HTML in the way that it interprets it best. You'll need to use a development environment to check the HTML syntax. Like visual studio...

Comment: Hey Koenyl I have updated the question a little bit. Hope you could help any more :).

Comment: Sho, that's a task, I've never tried anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

try the following link:

http://www.w3avenue.com/2010/01/04/list-of-free-web-based-html-editors-for-your-cms-project/

near the bottom for the page:
http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/